# Spyder's code analysis is not recognizing the tkinter imports. Is there any way to change this without changing the * to each item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I am doing from tkinter import *, but Spyder's code analysis is not recognising it.
Is there anyway to edit the preferences so Spyder recognises it?

Comment: Why not just use `import tkinter`, since `import *` is generally bad practice anyway?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) No, there's no way to make that happen. When you do

```
from tkinter import *
```

you're basically importing all symbols from the `tkinter` library in bulk. Due to that, it's not possible for our code analysis facilities to detect what symbols are part of that library and what others are not.

Instead of doing that, you should import just the TKinter classes or constants that you really need in your code.